# How to add up AngularJs iterated values in view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Suppose I am doing this

```
<div ng-repeat="order in orders">
   <p>order.productname</p>
   <p>order.productvalue</p>

</div>
```

Is there a way to calculate the total of all the productvalues in the view itself, or do I need to create a function in the controller?Can anyone point me to the right direction please? thanks

Comment: As far as I know there are no built-in methods, so the simplest way is to define sum function in `$scope`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to create a sum function in your controller which will calculate `total`:

```
<div ng-repeat="order in orders">
    <p>{{order.productname}}</p>
    <p>{{order.productvalue}}</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p>Total: {{total}}</p>
</div>
```

Or you can create a filter as in http://cacodaemon.de/index.php?id=55 and have the total sum directly filtered in your view:

```
<div ng-repeat="order in orders">
    <p>{{order.productname}}</p>
    <p>{{order.productvalue}}</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p>Total: {{orders|sumByKey:'productvalue'}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this

## In controller

```
$scope.numberOfItems= function(items){
  return items.length;
}
```

## in template

```
{{numberOfItems(orders)}}
```